# How do I make this 2 sqlite query into 1 by performing calculation?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 sqlite query to help to retrieve data and using dplyr to do a simple calculation. But I'm wondering if it is possible to complete both queries and calculations in 1 query.

I have a table that consists of

1. CRSDepTime with is a 24hour format timing for flights departure time.
2. ArrDelay and DepDelay which I use to remove flights that did not arrive on time

What I'm trying to do is to:

A) find the number of flights that are on time for each hour of the day

B) find the total number of flights for each hour of the day

C) divide (A/B)*100 to get percentage of flights that are on time for each hour of the day

first query:

```
q1_Days_NumOnTimeFlights <- dbGetQuery(conn,"
           SELECT
             flights.CRSDepTime/100 AS Time,
             COUNT(flights.CRSDepTime) AS NumOnTimeFlights
           FROM flights
           WHERE (flights.ArrDelay + flights.DepDelay) <=0
           GROUP BY CRSDepTime/100 
           ")
```

this gives me A which is number of ontime flights:

```
> head(q1_Days_NumOnTimeFlights)
  Time NumOnTimeFlights
1    0             6055
2    1             3057
3    2              712
4    3               34
5    4               30
6    5            43890
```

2nd query:

```
q1_Days_NumFlights <- dbGetQuery(conn,"
           SELECT
             flights.CRSDepTime/100 AS Time,
             COUNT(flights.CRSDepTime) AS NumFlights
           FROM flights
           GROUP BY CRSDepTime/100 
           ")
```

this gives me B which is total number of flights:

```
> head(q1_Days_NumFlights)
  Time NumFlights
1    0      10321
2    1       4813
3    2       1187
4    3         94
5    4         90
6    5      60384
```

currently I'm using dplyr to perform C. Filter, join and mutate the 2 queries.

```
q1_Days_Ans <- q1_Days_NumOnTimeFlights %>% 
  inner_join(q1_Days_NumFlights, by = "Time") %>% 
  mutate(percentage = (NumOnTimeFlights / NumFlights)*100) %>% 
  select(Time, percentage)
```

to get this result:

```
> head(q1_Days_Ans)
  Time percentage
1    0   58.66680
2    1   63.51548
3    2   59.98315
4    3   36.17021
5    4   33.33333
6    5   72.68482
```

I trying to do A,B,C in a single query, I've tried:

```
q1_Days_Ans <- dbGetQuery(conn,"
                            SELECT 
                                flights.CRSDepTime/100 AS Time,
                                ((COUNT(flights.CRSDepTime) FROM flights GROUP BY CRSDepTime/100) / (COUNT(flights.CRSDepTime) FROM flights WHERE (flights.ArrDelay + flights.DepDelay) <=0 GROUP BY CRSDepTime/100)*100) AS percentage
                            FROM flights
                            ")
```

But I'll get `Error: near "FROM": syntax error`

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation with `AVG()`:

```
SELECT CRSDepTime / 100 AS Time,
       100 * AVG(ArrDelay + DepDelay <= 0) AS percentage
FROM flights
GROUP BY Time;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8f7ac77201cb4bc74e4536bc0e30938d).

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I'm trying to find the percentage of OnTime flights which are flights that has total delay <= 0 against Total number of flights. But I believe AVG can only give an average. I'm not sure if I'm understanding it correctly

Comment: @Leo did you try it? AVG does the calculation that you need.

Comment: yes I did try. The ans I got is different from the ans from using dplyr. Do I have to add `WHERE (flights.ArrDelay + flights.DepDelay) <=0` somewhere?

Comment: since I'm taking the filtered delay count to divide by the non filtered delay count.

Comment: @Leo no there is no need for a WHERE clause. This is done inside the AVG() function which counts the number of rows where ArrDelay + DepDelay <=  0 and divides by the total number of rows. Create sample data in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 and post the link here so I can test it.

Comment: here you go https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6468bdb588a1d27ad84373b27e6d9105

Comment: @Leo in the sample data that yo posted: for 16:00 there are 4 rows all with ArrDelay + flights.DepDelay<=0 so the result is 100%, for 17:00 there are 17 rows and 6 of them with ArrDelay + flights.DepDelay<=0 so the result is 35.29% and for 19:00 there are 26 rows and 12 of them with ArrDelay + flights.DepDelay<=0 so the result is 46.15%. You can check the results here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8f7ac77201cb4bc74e4536bc0e30938d Where is the problem?

Comment: the data that I put into it is only a small fraction. The actual file is pretty big. I'm not sure how to use dbfiddle. I've uploaded the file here https://file.io/wDfwhgSlNy43 I'm sorry but this is the only way I know how to pass the data

Comment: @Leo there is no need to post the whole table. The code works as you can see in the fiddle and it works the same way for any number of rows.